# How to measure the traffic in OMNET++

Tags: simulation, omnet++, network-traffic

I am new to OMNET++.

In my simulation, there are several nodes generating packets. I want to get the aggregate traffic rate of those nodes. How can I measure the traffic in OMNET++?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to get aggregate statistics:

- Let INET collect statistics on a per node basis and aggregate those data with post processing
- Install the necessary `@statistics` listeners in the top level network module's NED file. Signals, that provide the statistics data propagate upwards in the topology tree upwards to the root node, so all signals emitted by ANYTHING in the network will be received by the top level (network) node essentially providing an aggregate value.

Obviously, the second approach is less flexible, as it does not work if you are interested in only *some* nodes' aggregate statistics (like statistics for all switches in the system).

Comment: Could you please elaborate the second option? Provide some examples or direct to some tutorials?